# Selenium how to call 'code' from other file (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I want to move some part of my code in `Selenium` to another project, because I plan to use this many times, in many tests.

At the beginning, most of my cases I need to login to service as admin, so I don't want to have this code in every test.

```
public void tc_mp_011() throws InterruptedException {

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + 10 * 1000;
while (true) {
    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signout']/div/div/div/span")).isDisplayed()) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() < end);
        else {
            System.err.println("timeout after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            end = start + 10 * 1000;
        }
        continue;
    } else {
        System.out.println("login Page loaded after " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        break;
    }
}

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("username")));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
end = start + 10 * 1000;


driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
a.sendKeys("admin");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("password")));
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
WebElement b = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
b.sendKeys("admin");

if (driver.findElement(By.id("username")).getAttribute("value").equals("admin") && driver.findElement(By.id("password")).getAttribute("value").equals("admin")) {

} else {
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin");
}


wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary")).click();

//step 1
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
end = start + 10 * 1000;
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#panel > div.panel-body > div.col-md-12 > div.controls > #enable")));


if (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
    try {
        while (
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#panel > div.panel-body > div.col-md-12 > div.controls > #enable")).isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Pageloaded after " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception nse) {

    }
} else {
    System.err.println("Fail - Page not loaded in 10s");
    org.testng.Assert.fail("Fail - Page not loaded in given time");
}

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#panel > div.panel-body > div.col-md-12 > div.controls > #enable")));
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("signedinusername"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(username, "admin"));


if (driver.findElement(By.id("signedinusername")).getText().equals("admin")) {} else {
    org.testng.Assert.fail("Fail - login as admin");
}

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();

}



@BeforeMethod

public void beforeMethod() {


System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("http://192.168.1.100./");

}

@AfterMethod

 public void afterMethod() {

  // Close the driver

   driver.quit();

}
```

I was trying to use `Page Object Pattern`, but I have with variables, I don't want to defice the one more time, and honestly I can't

eg `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` will open new instance of browser, and I don't want this.

Maybe there is a different simpler way to deal with this

I don't want to duplicate the code
I want to do something like this

```
Test1.
Common.loginAsAdmin(driver); //this is call to another class in another project
    Rest of Code (deleting users)

Test2.
Common.loginAsAdmin(driver); //this is call to another class in another project
    Rest of Code (creating users)

Test3.
Common.loginAsAdmin(driver); //this is call to another class in another project
    Rest of Code (modify users)

(...)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand exactly what you want. Your title say you want to call a class from another project, your text says you want to duplicate the code and the end you mix something related to Page Object.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please format your code. It's pretty hard to tell what's going on with this kind of formatting.

Comment: This is only my description, generaly I don't want to repeat the same code in every test, so I want to "call" if from other file, so in future changes will be simpler

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should have a suite of tests, in generally one method for each test, in case are you using Junit ,try this

```
 @Test
 public void testOne() { //all your Selenium code here}

 @Test
 public void testTwo() { //all your Selenium code here}
```

finally , if you need the conversation between those , try to using scope class variable instead

Answer (score 0):

you code is really messed up, you should clean that. If code reusability is what you are talking about create the function which you need to call and then call them in your tests. Don't write everything in your tests. To say the few problems

1. Elements are hard coded
2. All the logic is in the test so no code reusabilty.

I would suggest to google page object pattern and learn how to use it.

this would be good start though 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-to-implement-page-object-and-page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver